# DataGrid is not updating rows from List(of ) object

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, binding, properties

I already had this stuff working in another project but now it does not.
I have no more idea why.

1. Set DataGrid ItemsSource to `{Binding}`
2. Create new List(of myclass)
3. Create public list `Dim MyList As New List(of myclass)`
4. Bind `DataGrid.DataContext = MyList` when Instance is created
5. Set DataGrid Column definitions to some Items on the myclass properties

I added my first class on the list
`MyList.Add(New myclass())`
now, this item is visible. but after creating the instance and after the datagrid is visible, the rows do not update.
`MyList.Add(New myclass())` and no second row is visible.

Only when doing 
`MyDataGrid1.Items.Refresh`
the items are updated correctly.
But the List(of ) class already included the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface as far as I understand.

Any ideas why it fails?

here some additional code

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn         Header="N°"                 Binding="{Binding Path=LineNumber, StringFormat='{}{0:000}'}"           Width="SizeToCells"     MinWidth="30" IsReadOnly="True"  />

            <DataGridTextColumn         Header="HEX"                Binding="{Binding HexText}"         Width="SizeToHeader"    MinWidth="80" IsReadOnly="True"  FontWeight="Bold"                    />
            <DataGridTextColumn         Header="TextNormalized"     Binding="{Binding Description}"     Width="*"     MinWidth="80" IsReadOnly="True"  FontSize="12"       />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Some codebehind:

```
 Private ListData As New List(Of clsHexRowData)
```

Instance:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.dgv.ItemsSource = Me.ListData
    Me.ListData.Clear()
    Dim item As New clsQueueItem
    item.FromString("Hallo")
    Me.AddItem(item)
End Sub
```

this is visible, but when adding new rows after initializing the page, the items are not updated and a `dgv.Items.Refresh` is needed which I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ObservableCollection(of myclass) instead of list. you will see the changes when you add or remove items.

EDIT

```
 //add
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=> { Me.ListData.Add(new Item());}))
```

Comment: what a quick answer. thanks a lot. Now I understand, why my other (my first) project worked. Because I did not use the updated rows that way. Thanks blindmeis

Comment: Dear blindmeis. VS throws now an error because I need to add and remove items in Dispatcher thread. Is there a way to avoid going into the UI thread, the dispatcher thread?

Comment: you have to add them in the ui thread. the simplest way is to delegate your add and remove to the ui thread.

Comment: here is a nice thread how it works today and maybe with the next .net http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/16/wpf-45-observable-collection-cross-thread-change-notification